# Changing pandas column values into another format

Tags: python, pandas

The `labels` column in my `test['labels']` dataframe, looks like:

```
0                                      ['Edit Distance']
1                                   ['Island Perimeter']
2      ['Longest Substring with At Most K Distinct Ch...
3                                  ['Valid Parentheses']
4                      ['Intersection of Two Arrays II']
5                                           ['N-Queens']
```

For each value in the column, which is a string representation of list (`"['Edit Distance']"`), I want to apply the function below to convert it into an actual list.

`ast.literal_eval(VALUE HERE)`

What is a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Use `test['labels'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
import ast
test['labels'] = test['labels'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
print (test)
                                           labels
0                                 [Edit Distance]
1                              [Island Perimeter]
2  [Longest Substring with At Most K Distinct Ch]
3                             [Valid Parentheses]
4                 [Intersection of Two Arrays II]
5                                      [N-Queens]
```

Comment: could you explain how `pd.io.json.loads` works here? or any resource link?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - it should working here, beacuse list is valid json, but after testing not. so removed.